# Как открыть файл XML, который находится в решении ASP.NET приложения?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, доступ

```
 XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("Users.xml");
```

При компиляции  вылетает исключение- System.IO.FileNotFoundException "Файл 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\Users.xml' не найден.".

Файл Users.xml находится в папке с решением.

Искренне верю, что вариант с описанием полного пути к файлу не является единственным.

Comment: А с какими параметрами файл включён в проект? Какие у него Build Action и свойство Copy to Output Directory?

Comment: Если "Файл Users.xml находится в папке с решением.", то экзешник вашей программы лежит на 2 уровня ниже в `ПапкаПроекта\Debug\bin\`, т.е. XDocument.Load("Users.xml");` пытается его найти рядом в той же папке `\bin\`